# ASP MVC Add ApplicationUser to Generic Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

A few days ago I decide to use Unit of work & Generic repository In my project. After a little search [I found this solution](http://techbrij.com/generic-repository-unit-of-work-entity-framework-unit-testing-asp-net-mvc) to do this.

In this pattern we have 4 layer:

```
1. UI
2. Model
3. Repository
4. Service
```

The point is all domain models inheritance from  `Entity` class in model layer. For example :

```
public class Project : Entity<int> {
 ...
}
```

And this is my `Entity` class:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity { }
public abstract class Entity<T> : BaseEntity, IEntity<T>
{
    public virtual T Id { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I want to Add `ApplicationUser` class to UoF pattern I get an error with this concept that `ApplicationUser` is not inheritance from `BaseEntity`.

> Tip : `ApplicationUser` is inheritance from `IdentityUser` class

Whats the best practice to add `ApplicationUser` to my design pattern?

***UPDATE***

I get the error message in `IApplicationUserService` interface

```
public interface IApplicationUserService : IEntityService<ApplicationUser>
{
    Task<Part> GetById(int? id);
}
```

**IEntityService** :

```
public interface IEntityService<T> : IService
where T : BaseEntity
{
    void Create(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync();
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    Task Update(T entity);
}
```

Comment: Please show the error itself. It's not clear where it comes from.

Comment: Please see it again.

Answer (score 3):

The `IEntityService<T>` interface has a constraint so that each type that is provided as `T` needs to be derived from `BaseEntity`. As your `ApplicationUser` class is derived from `IdentityUser`, it cannot fulfill the constraint.

You can solve this in two ways:

1. Create a class for your users that is a real entity and therefore is derived from `BaseEntity` or `Entity<T>`. This way, the contraint is not violated. The class could be named `ApplicationUserEntity` or something like that. If you need to store an application user, you need to map the properties of the  `ApplicationUser` to the `ApplicationUserEntity`. You might also think about whether you really need the `ApplicationUser` class to be derived from `IdentityUser` and derive it from `BaseEntity` instead of creating a new class.
2. As an alternative, you can create an interface that every entity needs to implement. If your sample does show the complete `BaseEntity` class it does not have any members. So you can easily substitute `BaseEntity` by an interface, e.g. `IEntity`. You use this interface wherever `BaseEntity` is currently used, especially in the constraint. As a class can only be derived from one base class, but can implement several interfaces, you can implement `IEntity` in `ApplicationUser` so that you can use it as a type parameter for `IEntityService<T>`.

I'd favor the first approach as it avoids mixing authentication circumstances with persistence.

However, if you want to implement the second approach, first rename `BaseEntity`to `IEntity`, e.g. by accessing the context menu. This makes sure that the new name is used wherever `BaseEntity` was used before. Then change

```
public abstract class IEntity { }
```

to

```
public interface IEntity { }
```

Comment: I preferred second way. could you explain it with code?

Comment: @user3748973 I've extended the answer with a sample. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your question is not to try to push a square peg into a round hole. Answer this question for yourself: what good the generic repository will give you when applied to Identity part of your project?

I suspect there will be a lot of pain and swearing and a ton of custom code because `ApplicationUserManager` probably won't work with your solution and you'll have to write a custom storage or at least partly implement some of the logic.

Just because there is a pattern, does not mean you have to apply it everywhere. Especially places where the pattern does not fit.